# Import product and images when they already exist in pub/media

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, import

I'm downgrading my Magento from 2.4 to 2.3.5 because of Elasticsearch (not really relevant why). But to do so I thought it would be easier to just do a fresh install of Magento 2.3.5 database and all.

However I am running into a problem importing my old products. I exported them into the correct format and the check data comes back with no errors on the import screen.

When I go to submit it runs into an error "**1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 53, 55, 56, 58, 63**"

I am assuming it is because it is looking for the images in var/import and they are not there.

Is there anyway for me to import my products with the paths for where the images are located?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the product images you want to import are located in another folder you should copy them to a sub folder in

```
<Magento root folder>/var/import/images
```

Or create a symlink from this folder to the images. *You cannot import images via the file system outside of the var/import folder.*

Make sure your import file has the correct path to the images on the filesystem.

See the official documentation for more information : https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import-product-images.html